# Query mongo with operator or

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

If parameter is null - get all objects, if parameter isn't null - get objects with parameter.
I have query:

```
@Query("{$and : [{$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { topic : ?0 }]}] }")
    List<Event> find(Topic topic);
```

Where I run the method with topic = Topic.SPORT, I get :

> threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query
>   failed with error code 16722 and error message 'ReferenceError: SPORT
>   is not defined' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is
>   com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 16722
>   and error message 'ReferenceError: SPORT is not defined' on server
>   localhost:27017] with root cause

But if I run this method with topic = null, I get all objects (it's true)

I refactor this method as shown below:

```
@Query("{$and : [{$or : [ { $where: '\"?0\" == null' } , { topic : ?0 }]}] }")
    List<Event> find(Topic topic);
```

I can get the objects with my parameter topic = Topic.SPORT, but I can't get all objects where topic = null, I got empty list.
 How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I believe you need quotes around the ?0 in `{ topic : ?0 }`

Comment: @Bajal I want to get List<Event> independent by topic (which is my parameter) if topic = null

Comment: by default, mongorepository use And so you can remove the first $and

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you should check something first.
1. query for topic
topic : ?0
2. if null ~> true
$where: '\"?0\" == null'
it's your method but we have other way you can find in mongodocument (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/):

```
db.inventory.find( { item : { $type: 10 } } )
db.inventory.find( { item : { $exists: false } } )
```

The $type: 10 use went you save this field as null
and $exit to check this field avaiable or not.

After that, we have the combi of $or.
Hope you do it well